# How to show different layout in MultiWindow mode for android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-7.0-nougat, multi-window

Can we have some different layout in split window mode? And some different layout in full screen mode? Is it possible in android or not ?

Answer (score 0):

the following code shows how to specify an activity's default size and location, and its minimum size, when the activity is displayed in freeform mode:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
<layout android:defaultHeight="500dp"
      android:defaultWidth="600dp"
      android:gravity="top|end"
      android:minHeight="450dp"
      android:minWidth="300dp" />
```